N Queen problem with Evolutionary Algorithm
I am trying to solve a NQueen problem using Evolutionary algorithm but im not able to get desired output of my graph.
Following is the code I wrote
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import numpy as np

# Constants
N = 8  # Size of the N-Queens problem
POP_SIZE = 100  # Population size
GENERATIONS = 1000  # Number of generations
MUTATION_PROBABILITIES = [0.6, 0.8, 1.0]  # Mutation probabilities

# Fitness function to maximize non-attacking pairs  
def fitness(solution):
    non_attacking_pairs = 0
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(i + 1, N):
            if solution[i] != solution[j] and abs(i - j) != abs(solution[i] - solution[j]):
                non_attacking_pairs += 1
    return non_attacking_pairs  # Return the number of non-attacking pairs

def generate_population():
    return [random.sample(range(N), N) for _ in range(POP_SIZE)]

def select_parents(population):
    # Tournament selection for parents
    tournament = random.sample(population, 5)
    parent = max(tournament, key=fitness)  # Maximizing fitness
    return parent

def crossover(parent1, parent2):
    point = random.randint(1, N - 1)
    child1 = parent1[:point] + [x for x in parent2 if x not in parent1[:point]]
    child2 = parent2[:point] + [x for x in parent1 if x not in parent2[:point]]
    return child1, child2

def mutate(solution, mutation_rate):
    if random.random() < mutation_rate:
        i, j = random.sample(range(N), 2)
        solution[i], solution[j] = solution[j], solution[i]
    return solution

def next_generation(population, mutation_rate):
    new_population = []
    
    # Sort the population by fitness in descending order
    sorted_population = sorted(population, key=fitness, reverse=True)

    # Select parents and create the new population
    while len(new_population) < POP_SIZE:
        parent1 = select_parents(sorted_population)
        parent2 = select_parents(sorted_population)
        child1, child2 = crossover(parent1, parent2)
        
        # Mutate the children
        new_population.append(mutate(child1, mutation_rate))
        new_population.append(mutate(child2, mutation_rate))

    return new_population

# Evolutionary Algorithm with tracking of fitness values
def evolutionary_algorithm(mutation_rate):
    population = generate_population()
    best_fitness_values = []
    average_fitness_values = []

    for generation in range(GENERATIONS):
        # Evaluate fitness of current population
        fitness_values = [fitness(individual) for individual in population]
        best_fitness = max(fitness_values)  # Maximization
        average_fitness = np.mean(fitness_values)

        # Record best and average fitness
        best_fitness_values.append(float(best_fitness))  # Keep as float
        average_fitness_values.append(float(average_fitness))  # Keep as float

        # Generate the next generation
        population = next_generation(population, mutation_rate)

    return best_fitness_values, average_fitness_values

# Store average fitness values across mutation rates
overall_average_fitness = np.zeros(GENERATIONS)

# Run the evolutionary algorithm for each mutation probability
for mutation_rate in MUTATION_PROBABILITIES:
    best_fitness, average_fitness = evolutionary_algorithm(mutation_rate)

    # Accumulate average fitness values
    overall_average_fitness += np.array(average_fitness)

# Calculate the overall average fitness across mutation rates
overall_average_fitness /= len(MUTATION_PROBABILITIES)

# overall_average_fitness = np.round(overall_average_fitness)

# Plotting the results
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(range(GENERATIONS), overall_average_fitness, label='Overall Average Fitness', color='blue')
plt.title('Overall Average Non-Attacking Pairs Fitness Over Generations')
plt.xlabel('Generation')
plt.ylabel('Fitness (Number of Non-Attacking Pairs)')
plt.xticks(ticks=np.arange(0, GENERATIONS + 1, 100))  # Set x-axis ticks at intervals of 10
plt.grid()
plt.axhline(y=N * (N - 1) / 2 + 0.001, color='black', linewidth=0.1, linestyle='--', label='Max Non-Attacking Pairs')  # Max pairs line
plt.legend()
plt.show()


I tried changing population size, generation value but i still not able to get the smooth curve
My Output:My Output
Expected output fitness over generation:
Expected output Curve
How do i make that curve look smooth?

Why would you average results over different mutation rates (especially large ones)? If you want a smooth curve you need to have a large population size to reduce statistical noise, and you also want to take small steps so have a small mutation rate, finally you don't need too many generations just enough to reach the maximum fitness:
POP_SIZE = 1000  # Population size
GENERATIONS = 50  # Number of generations
MUTATION_PROBABILITIES = [0.001]  # Mutation probabilities



Hi thanks for the advice these changes helping me to get the almost similar outcome. The reason taking multiple mutations bcz the question has that requirement but with low mutation high population i am able achieve the graph. Thanks :)
